# Can the TextRank Algorithm be categorized as unsupervised machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, summarization

TextRank is an approach to Automatic Text Summarization. Many categorize it as an "unsupervised" approach. I wish to know if this translates into TextRank being categorized as an Unsupervised Machine Learning technique.

Answer (score 1):

TextRank is not directly related to machine learning: [Machine learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/Ujm7v/what-is-machine-learning) involves the creation of a data model to predict future observation based on previous observations. This involves tuning model parameters to fit observed data.

On the other hand, [TextRank](https://www.google.se/url?q=https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~mihalcea/papers/mihalcea.emnlp04.pdf) is a graph-based ranking algorithm: it finds the summary parts based on the structure of a single document and does not use observations to learn anything. Since it's not machine learning, it can't be unsupervised machine learning, either.

Answer (score 0):

The original authors of [TextRank](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=UetM7FgAAAAJ&citation_for_view=UetM7FgAAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C), Mihalcea and Tarau, described their work as `unsupervised` in a sense:

> In particular, we proposed and evaluated two innovative *unsupervised* approaches for keyword and sentence extraction.

However that differs from `unsupervised learning`, i.e. finding hidden structure within unlabeled data.

Also, TextRank is not a `machine learning` algorithm, in other words it does not generalize from data by "minimizing a loss function together with a regularization term or side constraints" (per [Stephen Boyd](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf), et al.). Linguists might not some similarities, though that's outside the scope of this question.

Even so, some confusion might come from the fact that TextRank and related approaches get used to develop *feature vectors* to present to machine learning algorithms.

Comment: The reason I asked this question is because I needed to gain clarity as there are conflicting opinions. I have read papers that consider PageRank as machine learning. More so machine learning on graphs (Sometimes called Graph Analytics). This book also considers it usupervised machine learning Friedman, J., Hastie, T., & Tibshirani, R. (2001). The elements of statistical learning (Vol. 1, pp. 241-249). New York: Springer series in statistics. To my understanding machine learning should not be tied to particular form of representing data.

Comment: So far, my top recommendation for books about ML is _The Master Algorithm_ by Pedro Domingos (U Washington) https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24612233-the-master-algorithm -- for the best overview of what is/isn't ML.